# MongoDB design [one collection and similar documents]

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm building app which is using MongoDB. In my app each user could have many different car models  (Porshe, ferrari etc).
I need to keep them all in one collection called - `car`. So in one collection i would like to store similar documents type. Why ? because these all models are cars and they all has from 50 till 90% the same fields.

question: am I right ? or i should have separated collection for each new car type (model) ?

Why I need it ? Because I have to show user some table with list of all his cars, and this table (GRID) has to be sorted and filtered as well.
filter by fields like number of doors, number of gears etc... it would be easier to rake these data from one collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using one collection is the way to go here.  But name it `cars` instead.